# Upload image from android to cakephp server

Tags: android, cakephp, http-post

Currently I'm working on building an app version for a web service so I trying to upload image from inside my android phone through an app to my cakephp webserver.

//android code

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String existingFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/New Folder/rsz_passportphoto.jpg";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        String responseFromServer = "";
        String urlString = "http://msm.icas.edu.sg/FANS/FANSweb/app/controllers/pagesext_controller.php";
        try
        {
         //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName) );
         // open a URL connection to the Servlet
         URL url = new URL(urlString);
         // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         System.out.println("Connected");
         // Allow Inputs
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         // Allow Outputs
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         // Don't use a cached copy.
         conn.setUseCaches(false);
         // Use a post method.
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
         dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         // create a buffer of maximum size
         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
         buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
         // read file and write it into form...
         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         while (bytesRead > 0)
         {
          dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
          bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
          bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
          bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         }
         // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
         // close streams
         Log.e("Debug","File is written");
         fileInputStream.close();
         Log.e("Debug","file input close");
         dos.flush();
         Log.e("Debug","flushed");
         dos.close();
         Log.e("Debug","closed");
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
             Log.e("Debug", "error 1 : " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
             Log.e("Debug", "error 2: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
              inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
              String str;

              while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
              {
                   Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
              }
              inStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ioex){
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
      }
```

It always comes out 
07-26 09:13:34.112: E/Debug(810): error: http://msm.icas.edu.sg/FANS/FANSweb/app/controllers/pagesext_controller.php
07-26 09:13:34.112: E/Debug(810): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://msm.icas.edu.sg/FANS/FANSweb/app/controllers/pagesext_controller.php

Comment: Even I am looking for a solution here. Did you find one?

Answer (score 0):

Read more: 
  http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html#ixzz21qi0MF72

or try this

//php code

```
<?php

$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
" has been uploaded";
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

?>
```

///The android code goes here

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

import android.util.Log;

public class HttpFileUploader implements Runnable{

URL connectURL;
String params;
String responseString;
InterfaceHttpUtil ifPostBack;
String fileName;
byte[] dataToServer;

HttpFileUploader(String urlString, String params, String fileName ){
try{
connectURL = new URL(urlString);
}catch(Exception ex){
Log.i("URL FORMATION","MALFORMATED URL");
}
this.params = params+"=";
this.fileName = fileName;

}


void doStart(FileInputStream stream){
fileInputStream = stream;
thirdTry();
}

FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
void thirdTry(){
String exsistingFileName = "asdf.png";

String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary = "*****";
String Tag="3rd";
try
{
//------------------ CLIENT REQUEST

Log.e(Tag,"Starting to bad things");
// Open a HTTP connection to the URL

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) connectURL.openConnection();

// Allow Inputs
conn.setDoInput(true);

// Allow Outputs
conn.setDoOutput(true);

// Don't use a cached copy.
conn.setUseCaches(false);

// Use a post method.
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );

dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + exsistingFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);




Log.e(Tag,"Headers are written");

// create a buffer of maximum size

int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
int maxBufferSize = 1024;
int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

// read file and write it into form...

int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

while (bytesRead > 0)
{
dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}

// send multipart form data necesssary after file data...

dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

// close streams
Log.e(Tag,"File is written");
fileInputStream.close();
dos.flush();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
// retrieve the response from server
int ch;

StringBuffer b =new StringBuffer();
while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){
b.append( (char)ch );
}
String s=b.toString();
Log.i("Response",s);
dos.close();


}
catch (MalformedURLException ex)
{
Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
}

catch (IOException ioe)
{
Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
}
}

}

Many of the headers included in the above file is not required, i was trying and failing :).

Now to upload file here is the java code from my activity class


public void uploadFile(){


try {
FileInputStream fis =this.openFileInput(NAME_OF_FILE);
HttpFileUploader htfu = new HttpFileUploader("http://11.0.6.23/test2.php","noparamshere", NAME_OF_FILE);
htfu.doStart(fis);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```