# Upload image from android to server using cakephp

Tags: android, image, cakephp, upload

I'm writing an android app that allow to upload image to server(use Cakephp). I can do with pure php like this solution: 
[Upload image from android to cakephp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666265/upload-image-from-android-to-cakephp-server)
My problem is that I don't know how to deal with my controller to move file to img directory of cakephp. I already try use the code bellow but it doesn't work. I'm really appreciate your assistant.

```
$target_path  = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']).
 " has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

This is code on android

```
try {

            // open a URL connection to the Server
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(newFile);
            URL url = new URL(url_upload);

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("profilepicture",
                    newFile.getAbsolutePath());

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\";filename=\""
                    + newFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"" + lineEnd));

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multiple part form data necessary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
            }
            // after download show image in gallery
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                    "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

Comment: `but it doesn't work` - in what way does it not work? A solution that works in php, will work in CakePHP (even if not the most appropriate) since Cake is written in ... php.  Compared the raw php the only real difference using Cake is that you should be referring to `$this->request->data` (`$this->data in older versions`) instead of using the `$_FILES` global.

Comment: Thanks, I've found the mistake. it's because of I don't have permission to write file on destination directory. now I did it.